# Search multiple categories (FIND_IN_SET)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have project in Codeigniter where user can search thorugh mulitple categories.
In my database, category field is comma separated string (46, 53, 76).

When user select category in filters (46) and match with first category in database, it works fine but, if user select another category (53), query doesn't work properly. Similar problem ocure when user select multiple categories.

My code is something like:

```
if(!empty($category)) {
        $cat_array = explode(',', $category);
        $count_items = count($cat_array);
        
        
        
        if($count_items == '1') {
            $this->db->where("find_in_set($category, po_category)");
        } else {
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            $this->db->group_start();
            $count = 0;
            foreach($cat_array as $item) {
                $count++;
                
                if($count == '1') {
                    $this->db->where("find_in_set($item, po_category)");
                } else {
                    $this->db->or_where("find_in_set($item, po_category)");
                }
            }
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
    }
```

I wonder if 'find_in_set' works in this structure.

Comment: How are you converting a multi select $category to a comma delimited string? And find_in_set, never used that before, couldn't you just do that in PHP?

Comment: I'm getting $category from html select2 multiselect where I get comma delimited string from html form

Comment: print your query and check what are you getting

Comment: Basically, when user choose multiple categories (2, 5, 9) I have to filter it in query where item categories stored like "2, 8, 11" .

Answer (score 1):

> In my database, category field is comma separated string (`'46, 53, 76'`).
>
> When user select category in filters (`46`) and match with first category in database, it works fine but, if user select another category (`53`), query doesn't work properly.

There is no `53` in your values list! It contains the value `' 53'` (with leading space char) which differs from the value to be searched for. And hence your searching gives negative result.

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(  53 , '46, 53, 76'),
       FIND_IN_SET( '53', '46, 53, 76'),
       FIND_IN_SET(' 53', '46, 53, 76');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81f440fd21b450924f21e769039ad1db

PS. Trailing spaces are taken into account too.

Answer (score 0):

There is space after comma in your `po_category` field.

So you need to remove it.

You can try like that.

```
$this->db->where("find_in_set($item, REPLACE(po_category, ' ', ''))");
$this->db->or_where("find_in_set($item, REPLACE(po_category, ' ', ''))");
```